# Размещение элементов

Tags: c#, wpf

Вот добавил stackPanel с кнопками и код с ошибками что не так:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:Taken15.ViewModels"
        xmlns:Models="clr-namespace:Taken15.Models" x:Class="Taken15.MainWindow"
        Title="Puzzle 15" Name="mainWindow" Width="500" Height="500" Background="#FF5B5B5B" MinHeight="320" MinWidth="320">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Button>Button 1</Button>
        <Button>Button 2</Button>
        <Button>Button 3</Button>
    </StackPanel>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModels:MainWindowVM/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding GameBackCommand}" Gesture="Ctrl + Z"/>
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding GameForwardCommand}" Gesture="Ctrl + F" />
    </Window.InputBindings>
    <!--вот здесь-->
    <ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding FieldCollection}" Margin="10">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    </Grid>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding PositionX}" />
                    <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding PositionY}" />
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                <Button Margin="3" Command="{Binding DataContext.GameBlockClickCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Value}" Content="{Binding Value}" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    <!-- и по сюда-->

</Window>
```

Comment: А какие именно ошибки и где?

Comment: Ну и код VM не мешало бы показать

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам необходимо добавить корневой элемент для страницы - Grid. Примерно так будет выглядеть код:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:Taken15.ViewModels"
    xmlns:Models="clr-namespace:Taken15.Models" x:Class="Taken15.MainWindow"
    Title="Puzzle 15" Name="mainWindow" Width="500" Height="500" Background="#FF5B5B5B" MinHeight="320" MinWidth="320">
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModels:MainWindowVM/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding GameBackCommand}" Gesture="Ctrl + Z"/>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding GameForwardCommand}" Gesture="Ctrl + F" />
</Window.InputBindings>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Button>Button 1</Button>
        <Button>Button 2</Button>
        <Button>Button 3</Button>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--вот здесь-->
    <ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding FieldCollection}" Margin="10">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                </Grid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding PositionX}" />
                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding PositionY}" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Margin="3" Command="{Binding DataContext.GameBlockClickCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Value}" Content="{Binding Value}" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
    <!-- и по сюда-->
</Grid>
```

У Window может быть только 1 корневой элемент, в котором лежат все остальные, например, Grid. В него ложится весь остальной контент. У вас же их было 2: StackPanel и ItemControl. DataContext и InputBindings выносятся на уровень страницы.

Comment: Я бы написал примерно так: `Window` - это `ContentControl`, поэтому он может иметь только один дочерний элемент - `Content`, если вам нужно разместить несколько элементов - придется их поместить в контейнер-панель, например `Grid` (или любой другой наследник `Panel`)